# Why do I get an error when I try to git commit --amend

Tags: git

I wanted to modify the commit message on a commit I just made, so I tried to do:

```
git commit --amend
```

(as I normally do), but I got an error:

```
Unable to find modified files; please check git status
```

Now this is strange, because I'm not trying to add/remove files from the commit, I just want to change the message, so it shouldn't matter whether I have modified files or not.

Can anyone explain this error message (and ideally, how I can get past it)?

*** EDIT ***

Mellowcandle requested my git status; here it is (more or less):

```
# On branch some_branch
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/some_branch' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   static/js/someFile.js
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   some/other/file
#   yet/another/file
```

*** EDIT #2 ***

The same problem occurs when I try to `git rebase -i` (with `reword`).

*** EDIT #3 ***

Here's the output of a `git config --list` (slightly anonymized), as requested by GoZoner:

```
user.name=My Name
user.email=email@example.com
push.default=upstream
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:someGitHubAccount/Apps.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.deploy.remote=origin
branch.deploy.merge=refs/heads/deploy
...*more branches that look similar*
```

Comment: Please post git status

Comment: What is the last commit? (Use `git log HEAD^..` to see it). Was it a merge commit?  Maybe you're trying to amend the commit _before_ that?

Comment: You have modified files, thus `git commit --amend` won't change the last commit. This can be done _only_ if the state is clean. The error message is confusing, I believe that was cleaned up recently. What version of git is that?

Comment: @vonbrand, are you sure? I can amend the last commit with a dirty working tree no problem

Comment: Okay, I have searched through the Git source now for all combinations of that error message and have found nothing. Are you sure you are using a real Git and not some wrapper that works in front of it? Also, which version of Git are you using?

Comment: @JonathanWakely, as long as the commit to be ammended doesn't touch any of the locally modified files, it should work. I wouldn't count on me not screwing up royally...

Comment: @poke if I do `which git` it shows `/usr/bin/git`, and I just have a standard (Linux Mint, ie. Ubuntu) installation of Git through `apt-get`, so I don't think there's any 3rd party software responsible for the message.  My Git version is 1.7.5.4, so perhaps I have a different version than what you're looking at?

Comment: @vonbrand I've tried stashing all local changes, but I still get the same error message, so it doesn't *seem* to be a locally modified file issue.

Comment: @machineghost I ran another test now for 1.7.5.4 but I still can’t find that message (or something similar). And Google also only knows this question for the message. That’s really weird.

Comment: @machineghost what is the output of `git --version` for your?

Comment: @Chronial I just provided it three comments before your comment.

Comment: Had a look at git and you are definitely not running a pure official git. That error message is not and has never been part of git.

Comment: If you say so, but I'm using the Ubuntu Linux version of Git, so that's pretty "standard" even if it isn't the "pure official git".

Comment: Regarding the ghost error message : do you have custom hooks installed ? Regarding the won't-be-amended-commit : what does this commit look like ? is it an empty commit ?

Comment: @LeGEC it was a custom hook!  If you submit your comment as an answer I'll be happy to award the bounty to you.

Comment: @Chronial I owe you an apology: you were dead on with your assessment that the message wasn't coming from Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you don't have a custom hook which triggers on commit.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could just do an interactive rebase on the parent of the current commit

```
git rebase -i head~
```

And then choose the `reword` option to change the commit message.

Comment: I am familiar with `git rebase -i`, but I really thought `git commit --amend` should work under these circumstances, so before I abandon the command entirely I'd (ideally) like to understand what's going on.

Comment: This is a bit belated, but I had the same issue happen to me again so I tried your approach.  First off `head~` should be `HEAD~`, right?  Second, even when I did that, the rebase editor popped up as expected, but when I saved the file with `reword` I got the same command line output: `Unable to find modified files; please check git status
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.`

Comment: In my case, (OS X) `head` is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

`git commit --amend` will work just like `git commit` just that it will recycle your old commit. So what this means is that it will expect that there are actually some changes in the index, ready to be committed.

So, if you want your `someFile.js` to be included, run `git add static/js/someFile.js` first. If you also want to track that untracked file, add that too using `git add some/other/file`.

Comment: You can amend a commit without any change in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git commit --amend --only`, and if that doesn't work then just try `git stash; git commit --amend ; git stash pop`. I'm not sure what state you're in here.

Comment: Neither --only or stashing before amending did any good; I got the same error message in both cases

Answer (score 1):

Do `git stash`. Then do `git commit --amend`.
After that do `git stash pop`.

Comment: "got" is the past tense of "git" and "get" is the future tense, obviously. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, both with and without modified, untracked files.

```
$ echo 'a' > a; git add -A; git commit -m 'a'
$ echo 'b' > b; git add -A; git commit -m 'b'

$ git log --oneline
63f2dd1 b
a0b364a a
$ git commit --amend
$ git log --oneline
d4cdeb7 bxx            # changed the commit message
a0b364a a

$ ed a # edit 'a'
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   a
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git commit --amend
$ git log --oneline
2d20e6e bxxyy           # changed the commit message again
a0b364a a

$ mkdir foo; echo 'c' > foo/c
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   a
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   foo/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git commit --amend
ebg@ebg(31)$ git log --oneline
09c1b26 bxxyyzz
a0b364a a
```

Comment: Yes, and it used to work for me too, on a different machine.  The point of the question though was to try and determine why it's not working on this machine.

Comment: I understand.  Have you done a `git config --list` and looked for anything strange?

Comment: I've added it to the answer; nothing looks strange to me (though I won't claim to be a Git config expert ...)

Comment: You have the same problem on a brand new `git` repository on the same machine?  Do you have access to another machine to try there?  Can you install another `git` version?